# DirectX 11 Win8 SDK. Is there any GUI?

Tags: user-interface, directx

I have been working on my own Little Graphics Engine for a while and i have come to a Point where i need a robust GUI. Does anybody know if this exist to the win 8 DirectX sdk? I have had problems with CEGUI. I have been searching all over the web but I cannot find anything. The Controls I need is buttons, scrollbars, childwindows/panels whatever so nothing too complicated and it doesn't need to look very good either.

Simple question as that :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are writing a Windows Store app, the recommendation is to use XAML for GUI controls. For DirectX interop within XAML, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh825871.aspx) article.

Otherwise most DirectX apps create their own GUI systems or use an existing middleware solution like Scaleform, etc.

For a Win32 desktop app, you can make use of the old [DXUT](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320437) GUI elements.

Comment: Thanks, didnt know there was a win 8 version of DXUT :)

Comment: There's a DXUT11 that has been updated to not use D3DX or Direct3D 9 so you can build with just the Windows 8.x SDK and not need the legacy DirectX SDK at all. It's for Win32 desktop applications that run on Windows Vista SP2+KB[971644](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971644), Windows 7, Windows 8.0, or Windows 8.1. It does not support Windows Store apps, Windows phone 8, or Xbox One.